# how to multi-row insert in Oracle with sequence?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want insert more than one row into table in Oracle . But it's confused me :
I can not use

```
select seq_table1.nextval  into table1 form dual
```

because the the table1 need be a new one. I need insert  some rows into the exist table1.

And I  also can  not use

```
insert into pager (PAG_ID,PAG_PARENT,PAG_NAME,PAG_ACTIVE)
          (select seq_paper.nextval,'Multi 8000',1 from dual
 union all select seq_paper.nextval,'Multi 8001',1 from dual)
```

because oracle tell me that:

```
Restrictions on Sequence Values You cannot use CURRVAL and NEXTVAL in the  
following constructs:  
■ A SELECT statement that is combined with another SELECT statement with the  
UNION, INTERSECT, or MINUS set operator ;
...and other constructs
```

Comment: thank you very much , I'll learn to eidt it with markDown

Answer (score 2):

You can rephrase the `select` so that the `nextval` is not in a `union`.

The result would be something like:

```
insert into pager (PAG_ID,PAG_PARENT,PAG_NAME,PAG_ACTIVE) 
    select seq_paper.nextval, NULL, a, b from 
        (select 'Multi 8000' a, 1 b from dual 
         union all 
         select seq_paper.nextval,'Multi 8001',1 from dual)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use nextval once and create data inside sub query:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE pager (PAG_ID NUMBER,PAG_PARENT VARCHAR2(10), PAG_ACTIVE NUMBER);
Table created

SQL> CREATE SEQUENCE seq_paper START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 NOMAXVALUE;
Sequence created

SQL> 

SQL> INSERT INTO pager
  2      (pag_id,
  3       pag_parent,
  4       pag_active)
  5      SELECT seq_paper.nextval,
  6             pag_parent,
  7             pag_active
  8        FROM (SELECT 'Multi 8000' pag_parent,
  9                     1 pag_active
 10                FROM dual
 11              UNION ALL
 12              SELECT 'Multi 8001',
 13                     1
 14                FROM dual);
2 rows inserted

SQL>
```